# How to copy a string to a unsigned char* on a struct?

Tags: c++, windows

a.h

```
struct loader_struct
{
    unsigned char* loader_x64;
};

extern loader_struct* g;
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

loader_struct g_startup;
loader_struct* g = &g_startup;
```

b.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string mdata = "abcdefg";
    g->loader_x64 = new unsigned char[mdata.length()];
    std::copy( mdata.begin(), mdata.end(), g->loader_x64 );
}
```

I'm trying to copy the content of `mdata` to `loader_x64`, its being copied, however, it contains some rubbish at the ending, what im doing wrong?

Comment: `mdata.length()` does not include the null terminator; neither does the begin / end range.  You have the same issue with C strings and `strlen()`. There *must* be duplicates of this question. Hundreds of them.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the string? What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Do you really need to copy the string, isn't it enough to copy the pointer to the string?

Comment: Oh, and your code is leaking memory. Don't use owning pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting "rubbish" because whatever code is reading from `loader_x64` is expecting it to be null-terminated, but you are not actually null-terminating it, so the reader reaches past the end of the buffer, which is *undefined behavior*.

You need to null-terminate the `loader_x64` buffer, eg:

```
#include "a.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string mdata = "abcdefg";
    g->loader_x64 = new unsigned char[mdata.length()+1];
    std::copy_n( mdata.c_str(), mdata.length()+1, g->loader_x64 );
    ...
    delete[] g->loader_x64;
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply set `loader_x64` to point directly at `mdata`'s internal data, which is guaranteed to be null-terminated since C++11, eg:

```
#include "a.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string mdata = "abcdefg";
    g->loader_x64 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(mdata.data()); // C++17 and later
    or
    g->loader_x64 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char*>(mdata.c_str())); // prior to C++17
    ...
}
```